# The antialias of rotated CGImage/CGlayer seems jaggy, UIImageView's is not

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, cgimage, cglayer

I need to **mask** a "texture" image with a **rotated** greyscale image.

I found out, that I have to do it with *CGImages* or *CGlayers* (if there is a simplier way using *UIImageViews* only, please let me know about it).

My problem is simple:

> The **antialias** of any
>   rotation-transformed CG stuff is quiet
>   **jaggy**...

... but the antialias of a rotation-transformed UIImageView is kinda perfect. How can I produce that beautiful antialiased rotations?

I've uploaded a "proof" involving actual iPhone Simulator screenshots, to see what am I talkin' about: http://gotoandplay.freeblog.hu/files/Proof.png

I've tried to use *CGImages*, *CGLayers*, *UIImageViews* "captured" with *renderInContext*, I've tried to *CGContextSetInterpolationQuality* to high, and also tried to set *CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing* - *CGContextSetShouldAntialias*, but every case returned the same jaggy result.

I'm planning to learn using OpenGL next year, but this development should released using CoreGraphics only. Please let me know how to get a perfectly rendered rotated image, I just can't accept it's impossible.

Comment: Hi geri, did you find any solution to this problem? I am facing similar issues here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590470/how-do-i-remove-those-rotation-artefacts-from-my-catiledlayer

Comment: Ya. Every solution was really performance demanding, so I decided to learn the OpenGL ES API. It is not as big deal, and game become really smooth both in antialias, and the performance.

Comment: Seems look like rotated aliased plane textured with anti-aliased image.

Answer (score 1):

To add 1px transparent border to your image use this

```
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( imageRect.size ); 
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(1,1,image.size.width-2,image.size.height-2)];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a clear, 1 pixel border around your image? I've heard of that recommended as a trick to avoid aliasing, by giving CoreGraphics some room to work with when blending the edges.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem, looks like I'm going to move it over to OpenGL ES as well. I can't nail down an effective solution that doesn't hurt performance.

For reference of future CoreGraphics explorers, putting a 1-pixel transparent border did make for a noticeable improvement in my experiments, but it appears that as Eonil mentioned, you end up with multiple stages of antialiasing/smoothing/interpolation working against each other. IE: CGLayer does some interpolation for it's rotation, then context it's being drawn to will do some interpolation/antialiasing, so on so forth until it ends up looking pretty rough.

I actually ended up with better results by disabling interpolation and antialiasing on the destination context, though it was still obviously jaggy (less artifacts overall though). I was able to achieve the best overall appearance by enabling interpolation and antialiasing when constructing the CGLayer, and disabling it for the destination context when re-drawing it.  This approach, obviously, is fraught with other problems.